# Record video in android without audio

Tags: android, video

I'm working on a project and I'm curious to know if its possible to configure the `MediaRecorder` in Android to record just the video and exclude audio, i.e.

```
mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL);
mRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
```

changed to something along the lines of

```
mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
mRecorder.setAudioSource(null);
mRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
```

When I try to do the above, I get different exceptions when I either try to initialize the `MediaRecorder` or when I try to start the recording.

According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html#setAudioSource%28int%29), it would seem that I can do this.

> If this method is not called, the output file will not contain an audio track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue I was having was a result of using a `CamcorderProfile`.  Once that was removed, I no longer had issues building the project.  As CodeX mentioned, there is no need to have an audio source.